# Material UI Card alignment listing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI to create the cards with grid container.

But Grid item will have same height for each row, how can I make the bottom card close to the top one when having white space? and the last card I wish to stick to the left instead of middle.
See the image below:
[image]

This is the look and feel I wish to achieve.

[image]

My example code:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-northcutt-8slxi)

Is it achievable by using Material Grid container or something else? or I have to create my own css? Please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve what I am try to by using flex-direction=column.
But I need split my data into few column, is it worth to do it?

Any other solution?

```
<Grid container spacing={3} className={classes.container}>
  <Grid item xs={6} md={4} lg={3}>
    <Grid container direction='column'>
      <Grid item>
        <Card></Card
      </Grid> 
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6} md={4} lg={3}>
    <Grid container direction='column'>
      <Grid item>
        <Card></Card
      </Grid> 
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```